# Find records that STARTS with whatever, in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using this to find documents that 'contains' whatever string, in a Mongodb collection:

`$query[(string) $mongo_record] = array( '$regex' => (string) $value );`

Then:

`$results = $collection->find( $query );`

What should I do to find records that 'start' with x string?

Thank you

Comment: If your string was `x` then the regex would be: `/^x.*/`

Comment: I tried a couple of things, one of them being:

`$query[(string) $mongo_record] = array( '$regex' => "/^".(string) $value.".*/" );`

Would you know how to correctly do it in PHP?

Thx

Comment: You wanna use the `MongoRegex` object

Comment: On that note, if you're concatenating `$value` directly into a regular expression, you may want to filter it through [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) with the appropriate delimiter (`/` in your case).